# Is it possible to decide the level of indirection of a pointer at runtime using C?

Tags: c, pointers

Is it possible to declare a pointer-to-pointer-to-...-to-[data type] whose level of indirection is decided at runtime?

This is a thought experiment; I am aware that this is probably awful practice and I have no intentions of actually using it for anything. But I spent several hours thinking about it and abusing preprocessor macros and came up empty, so I'm curious if someone can figure out how to do this:

Write a program that takes as input an `int` `m` (up to 255) from `stdin` and declares an `m`-level-indirected pointer to `int`. i.e. if the input is 4, it should declare `int ****x;` in the top level scope of `main()`.

Comment: There is no particular support for this in C. It can be effected by writing your own routines to iterate through repeated dereferences and conversions. There is generally no need for it in practical software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I know. I'm just curious to see an implementation, since I suspect I will learn something interesting from doing so.

Comment: You can always cast, dereference, and cast again. That's not even hard. Why you would do this I don't even know. `void* x = y; x = (void*) *x;` etc.

Comment: IMO it is X-Y problem. Does not make too much sense

Comment: C is a statically-typed language. You cannot create new types at runtime.

Comment: @RaymondChen More generally, you cannot create declarations at runtime.

Comment: That's more or less where I landed when I started playing with this, but I wanted to see if I was just missing something. Apparently not.

Comment: You can fake it with `union PP { PP* next; int* last; };` Though not celar why you'd need this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change declarations at runtime.  But you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int count = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 5;
        int d = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0) : 10;
        void *f[10];
        int dereferenced;

        if( count > 5 ) {
                fprintf(stderr, "levels of direction must be <= 5\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        f[0] = &d;
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                f[i] = f + i - 1;
        }
        switch(count) {
        case 1:dereferenced = *(int *)f[0];
        case 2:dereferenced = **(int **)f[1];
        case 3:dereferenced = ***(int ***)f[2];
        case 4:dereferenced = ****(int ****)f[3];
        case 5:dereferenced = *****(int *****)f[4];
        }
        printf ("%d\n", dereferenced);
}
```

Comment: the problem arises when more than one type is needed :D

Comment: Yea, the switch method is doable. Was wondering if there was a way to do it without basically making all the possible declarations and then picking out the one you want. Seems like the answer is no. Thanks!

Comment: This causes UB by violating the strict aliasing rule . The case 2 should be `*(int *)*(void **)f[1]` and so on